# reset CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am building a subset of the packages in my catkin workspace using CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES. However, when I want to rebuild the whole workspace (without CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES set), it still only builds the whitelisted packages. I assumed that the whitelist is only temporary for each build, but it seems like it is globally stored. I couldn't find any documentation on it.

If I want to change the whitelist, the only thing I can do is to remove `build` and `devel`. Can anyone provide me with some more information about CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES, i.e. what exactly it does and where it is stored?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257055/reset-catkin_whitelist_packages/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2017-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Search for `CATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES` in the ROS wiki returned the following page. It describes the usage of that variable and how to revert back to building all packages: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/commands/catkin_make

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2017-03-15**:
what the h***, I am pretty sure I was on this page, but somehow I must have overlooked it. Thanks a lot anyway!

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-03-15**:
Please mark the answer as correct then so that other's searching for the same problem can find it easier.